# Can I integrate or import code from Visual Studio Code to Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Is there any way I can use Visual Studio Code and somehow integrate it to Microsoft Visual Studio just to use for version control after I'm done?

I mainly code with HTML, CSS, and Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just load the folder in VS Code and edit the files.
VSCode is not able to handle solution files so any adding or deleting will need to be done in the full Visual Studio IDE.
You will be able to edit the files in VSCode though and I do believe it supports the Source Control integration as well.

Comment: "should be able to" and "I do believe" are not phrases one expects to see in a quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

vscode has source control. and in same boat but reverse.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34400691)